# How to debug CSS bundled by Webpack?

Tags: css, webpack, postcss, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

I've switched from including stylesheets the oldschool way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./../css/main.css">
```

to Webpack approach:

```
var css = require('./../css/main.css');
```

It works, but I don't like that it extracts the css from this file into inline  tag, because then it's harder to debug it in Dev Tools. For example I have no idea from which file and line these attributes are coming from:
[image]

How can I move it to separate file or generate a source map that would point me to the source file? So when I inspect it Dev Tools it will look like this:

[image]

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
    devtool: "css-loader?sourceMap",
    module:  {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'},
            {
                test:   /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    entry:   [
        './static/js/app.js'
    ],
    output:  {
        filename: './static/js/bundle.js'
    },
    watch:   false,
    postcss: function () {
        return [autoprefixer];
    }
};
```

My `app.js`:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
require('bootstrap-loader');

module.exports = (function () {
    alert('IT WORKS!');
});

window.app = module.exports;
var css = require('./../css/main.css');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract your styles from your bundle to an external stylesheet you need to use [extract text plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin).

The general webpack config looks like this:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: 'path/to/entry.js',
    output:  {
        path: 'path/to/bundle'
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module:  {
        loaders: [
            {
                test:   /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtracTextPlugin.extract('css-loader?sourceMap')
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
         new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
    ]
};
```

The parts that you should notice are using `devtool: "source-map"` for the debugging part and that with the plugin you provide the loader as the parameter to extract method of the plugin:

```
loaders: [
    {
        test:   /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtracTextPlugin.extract('css-loader?sourceMap')
    }
]
```

Here you can also chain loaders if you need for example `sass-loader` too:

```
loaders: [
    {
        test:   /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtracTextPlugin.extract('css-loader?sourceMap!sass-loader?sourceMap')
    }
]
```

You don't need the style-loader anymore but you can also provide it as a fallback loader to the plugin:

```
loaders: [
    { 
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
            loader: "css-loader?sourceMap"
        })
    }
]
```

and in your plugins array you instantiate the plugin and provide the name you want for the external stylesheet:

```
plugins: [
     new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
]
```

You can also use `[name]` placeholder if you have multiple entry points and you will have a stylesheet per entry.

Comment: Thanks, the file is generated, but now I still have to include this `styles.css` into template by `<link>` tag?

Comment: This mapping doesn't make sense - it points to scss file, but the file generated by ExtractTextPlugin, not the real source file. So if I would bundle 2 scss together the mapping would point to the bundle, instead of 1 of those 2 files.

Comment: My bad, I was extracting into scss, instead css. But still [I cannot get those mappings right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680721/extracttextplugin-no-scss-mapping-in-main-css-map).

Comment: @van_folmert: As you already noticed you have to use sourceMap queries on loaders themselves too.
About the first question you can use the [html webpack plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin) to generate an html file based on a template and insert your bundles automatically in it on every build.

Comment: plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
    ]