# extract-text-webpack-plugin - extracting scss results in no mapping in main.css.map

Tags: css, sass, webpack

I've managed to extract 2 scss files into 1 css file, but I've noticed the source and mappings in `main.css.map` are empty:

```
{"version":3,"sources":[],"names":[],"mappings":"","file":"./main.css","sourceRoot":""}
```

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module:  {
        loaders: [
                {test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'},
                { 
                    test:   /\.scss$/,
                    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css', 'sass'])
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    entry:   [
        './static/js/app.js'
    ],

    output:  {
        filename: './static/js/bundle.js'
    },

    watch:   false,

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("./main.css")
    ]
};
```

My `app.js`:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
require('bootstrap-loader');

module.exports = (function () {
    alert('IT WORKS!');
});

window.app = module.exports;

require('./../css/main.scss');
require('./../css/main2.scss');
```

`webpack`'s output from terminal:

```
Hash: 28bc2c1ea9d333be2975
Version: webpack 1.13.3
Time: 3500ms
                               Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg    109 kB          [emitted]
               ./static/js/bundle.js    666 kB       0  [emitted]  main
                          ./main.css    126 kB       0  [emitted]  main
           ./static/js/bundle.js.map    813 kB       0  [emitted]  main
                      ./main.css.map  87 bytes       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
   [1] ./static/js/app.js 287 bytes {0} [built]
    + 29 hidden modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
        + 4 hidden modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
        + 4 hidden modules
```

As you can see `main.css` is generated along with `main.map.css`, but at this point it's pretty useless, because inside there is no mapping at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after struggling with numerous combinations, I figured it out. Syntax for using these css loaders can give a headache and apparently was changed as webpack evolved, because some older examples that work for others oddly didn't work for me.

Despite already having `devtools: 'source-map'` option I also needed to change loaders from:

```
{ 
    test:   /\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css', 'sass'])
}
```

into:

```
{
    test:   /\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader?sourceMap', 'sass-loader?sourceMap'])
}
```

and thanks to this inspecting my css file in Dev Tools is correctly pointing to both scss files now.